# php regex - find string within string

Tags: php, regex

I need to identify a string that can contain 1- 6 # symbols inside another string and retrun the start position of the substring and the substring itself.

for example:

`example ## string => [strpos=> 9, stren => 2]`

so far I have this:

`/["#"]{1,6}/gm`

Can anyone help?

Comment: `strpos` will give you the position.

Comment: there is no such thing as "a string in a string"

Comment: @PhilippSander ... just out of curiosity, how would you define a substring then?

Comment: Note you should not use `g` modifier in PHP regex, and `m` is not necessary here since there is no `^` and `$`.

Comment: And, what do you intend to do with the offset information ? And, you won't get a length value in any php regex functions. Unless this is for educational purposes, maybe explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `preg_match` (or `preg_match_all` to get multiple matches) with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` argument:

```
$str = "example ## string";
if (preg_match('~#{1,6}~', $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    print_r($m);
}
```

See [PHP `preg_match` reference:](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-match.php)

> **PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE**
>   If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of **`matches`** into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset *0* and its string offset into **`subject`** at offset *1*.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/cHQAtf), output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ##
            [1] => 8
        )

)
```